# Unable to import SGD and Adam from 'tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

**Trying to run---**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam

import numpy as np

print(tf.__version__)
```

**I get this error---**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-f05f8f753c47> in <module>()
      4 from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
      5 from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
----> 6 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
      7 
      8 import numpy as np

ImportError: cannot import name 'SGD' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm studying machine learning in Google Colab.
I pasted the example code and run it, and get error message.

I could find similar errors in Google, but I couldn't find anything to solve this problem.

I tried 'from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam', 'from tf.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam', and 'from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam'.
But everything didn't work.

Comment: for me 'from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam' works on google colab. have you tried using a new notebook or resetting the runtime etc.?

Comment: Yes, I tried them. And I tried that code on VScode and jupyter notebook, but the same error message was printed out.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v1 import SGD
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the exact updated alias name while importing the model([Sequential](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential)),layers ([Flatten](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten), [Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense)) and optimizers ([SGD](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD), [Adam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam)).

Please try again using the below code in new `Google Colab` notebook.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential  #removed python from each layer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam

import numpy as np

print(tf.__version__)
```

Output:

```
2.8.2
```